# Behat + Symfony2MockerExtension: Session has no access to client container

Tags: behat

My composer:

```
"require-dev": {
    "polishsymfonycommunity/symfony2-mocker-extension": "*",
    "behat/gherkin" : "~2.2.9",
    "behat/behat": "v2.4.6",
    "behat/symfony2-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-extension": "*",
    "behat/mink-goutte-driver": "*",
    "behat/mink-selenium2-driver": "*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "3.7.29"
},
```

My feature:

```
Feature: Submitting contact request form
  Scenario: Submitting the form
    And CRM API is available
    Then the contact request should be sent to the CRM
```

Behat's error:

```
Feature: Submitting contact request form
  Scenario: Submitting the form
    And CRM API is available
      Session has no access to client container
    Then the contact request should be sent to the CRM
```

I've added getContainerBaseClass in mi app/AppKernel()

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
protected function getContainerBaseClass()
{
    if ('test' == $this->environment) {
        return '\PSS\SymfonyMockerContainer\DependencyInjection\MockerContainer';
    }

    return parent::getContainerBaseClass();
}
```

And new sentence in my FeatureContext:

```
class GeeftyContext extends MinkContext
    implements KernelAwareInterface, ServiceMockerAwareInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ServiceMocker $mocker
     */
    private $mocker = null;

    /**
     * @param ServiceMocker $mocker
     * @return null|void
     */
    public function setServiceMocker(ServiceMocker $mocker)
    {
        $this->mocker = $mocker;
    }

    /**
     * @Given /^CRM API is available$/
     */
    public function crmApiIsAvailable()
    {
        $this->mocker->mockService(
            'my_service',
            'Acme\Bundle\My\ServiceClass'
        )->shouldReceive('method')->once()->andReturn(true);
    }

    /**
     * @Then /^the contact request should be sent to the CRM$/
     */
    public function theContactRequestShouldBeSentToTheCrm()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Symfony Mocker Extension only works with the Symfony2 mink driver. I'm guessing you're trying to use it with one of the other drivers.

It's technically impossible to use it with a driver other than Symfony2. When using drivers like selenium2 or goutte, the request is handled in a separate process (while it's the same process in case of the Symfony2 driver).

The exception message [is a bit missleading](https://github.com/PolishSymfonyCommunity/Symfony2MockerExtension/blob/e940f314a4b957512d99abfbd76f5572ff272883/src/PSS/Behat/Symfony2MockerExtension/ServiceMocker.php#L108). I encourage you to send a PR to [the project](https://github.com/PolishSymfonyCommunity/Symfony2MockerExtension/) to improve it.

Edit: as mentioned in [Symfony2MockerExtension#5](https://github.com/PolishSymfonyCommunity/Symfony2MockerExtension/issues/5#issuecomment-36240669), the extension will only work with a symfony2 session. You can set it as a default as in the example below, or annotate the features/scenarios with `@mink:symfony2`.

```
default:
  context:
    class: 'Acme\DemoBundle\Features\Context\FeatureContext'
  extensions:
    PSS\Behat\Symfony2MockerExtension\Extension: ~
    Behat\Symfony2Extension\Extension:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      default_session: symfony2
      show_cmd:  open %s
      base_url:  'http://my.web/site/'
      selenium2: ~
      goutte:    ~
```